# How can I do this calculation in php?

Tags: php, math

I want to do this calculation in PHP:

```
10000*(0.011*(1.1^148))
```

If I run this through a calculator the result is `147065257,797835` (I want to round it to `147070000`.)

I ran this in PHP

```
echo round(10000*(0.011*(1.1^148)), 1);
```

and the output was `16390`. Why does it show a completly different result from my calculator? What can I change to make the result to `147065257,797835`?

Comment: ^ is bitwise XOR, not "to the power of"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponential expression is used as function and not with caret  as shown below:

```
$sum = 10000*(0.011*pow(1.1, 148));

echo round($sum, -4);
```

I've also corrected your rounding for the desired output.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php